# A2LiX Translation Form labels options

Tags: symfony, doctrine-extensions, a2lix-translation

I'm using KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/Translatable and A2LiX Translation Form to translate my entities in a Symfony application. It works very well. However, when the form is rendered there is a "translations" title that I would like to delete and a "EN [Default]" text on a tab that I would like to change.

In the examples of the doc, there's a "medias" example so I imagine that we can change this text. Moreover, the tabs don't have this [Default] text. So I imagine that's possible to change them.

[image]

And this is mine:

[image]

Does anybody know how to do it? If we take a look on the form type options we don't see anything concerning the "Translations" label. For the "Default", I can't see where I should search for it.

Answer (score 1):

For the "translations" title, I was able to override it adding a label to the form type just like a normal field. However, it is not possible to use a blank value. I had to use ' ' in order to override the text.

```
->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', array(
            'label' => ' ', --> this overrides the translations title
            'fields'    => array(
                'name'   => array(
                    'field_type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'blabla'
                ),
                'description'   => array(
                    'field_type' => 'textarea',
                    'label' => 'bleble',
                )
            )
        ))
```

For the "Default" label, I still have no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Default template file is located at `vendor/a2lix/translation-form-bundle/A2lix/TranslationFormBundle/Resources/views/default.html.twig`. If you want you can specify your own template and set it in `config.yml` file, like this:

```
a2lix_translation_form:
    ....
    templating: "@SLCore/includes/translation.html.twig"
```

More information can be found [here](http://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/#bundle-configuration).

Comment: Thanks @xurshid29, I hadn't seen the "default" the other day but your are right. It's in an "ul" list.